# Product or sum of invertible matrix give an invertible matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I can't find out if the product of two invertible matrix is an invertible matrix or if the sum of two invertible matrix is an invertible matrix.

Can anyone suggest an answer/counterexample?

Thanks a lot in advice

Comment: Try real numbers first.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

1. For the sum, think about how the zero matrix can be a sum of invertible matrices.
2. For a product of matrices, think about how you would solve the equation $(A\cdot B)\cdot x = b$ if you are given an arbitrary vector $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\det(AB)=\det A \det B$ or $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$.

For sum $I-I=0$

Comment: Ok so since $detA\neq 0$ and since $detB\neq 0$ $det(AB)\neq 0$ and $AB$ is invertible?

Comment: yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Let $A_1 = -I_n$ and $A_2 = I_n$. Then $A_1 + A_2$ is the zero matrix hence not invertible.

(2) Let $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ be invertible matrices. Now let $X$ be the product of these invertible matrices. So, $$X = \prod_{i}A_i.$$ $X$ is also invertible, because $$det(X) = \prod_i det(X_i) \neq 0.$$